# how to measure query execution time in seqilize?

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js

How can I calculate the execution time of a query Seqilize ORM?

- There is a build in function that measures it?
- How can I manage the
  running queries(PROCESS LIST)?
- How do I know how many connections running?

Comment: Here it is in the documentation... "options.benchmark" 

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To print execution time of the query insert `logging` and `benchmark` options to it like that:

```js
const game = await Game.findAll({
    benchmark: true,
    logging: console.log,
    <...>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to log execution time for all queries run by sequelize you might want to configure this globally:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  benchmark: true,  // <-- this one enables tracking execution time
  logging: (sql: string, timingMs?: number) => logger.info(`${sql} - [Execution time: ${timingMs}ms]`),
  <...>
});
```

The link from comments to benchmark configuration is outdated. Here are the new ones for [query level](https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/queryoptions#benchmark) and [global](https://sequelize.org/api/v7/interfaces/options#benchmark)

Comment: Tested as of sequelize 6.14.0 the custom `logging` option is not strictly necessary, `logging: console.log` already shows the `Elapsed time: 0ms` at the end by default. Good to know that it can also be used on custom logs though.